# Change Look of Classic List

Tags: list, web-part, css, design

How can I change the look of this list?

In classic view, the space in between the question and the text box to be filled up is too big.

Is this a change web part? and if so what formula may I use?

[image]

Comment: That's not normal behaviour. Do you have any custom masterpage layout or any CSS in the displayform of the list? It looks as if the table is set yo 100% width of the windows rather than just use whatever space it needs.

It should be a simple fix to add a bit of CSS to the display form to make the table ignore any width=100% property, but if it was my I would want to know why this happens in the first place.

Comment: Hi I do not, in fact I have not touched any web part. However, I do have lines that are of multiple text (10 lines) that exist within the list. The list is extremely long. Aside from this, I really don't know what else I did but I can assure you i didn't touch the CSS as well

Comment: Does this occur on all lists? And just to state the obvious: You don't have any really long question further down the form? It will not honor line breaks so that could be the reason as well.

Comment: My apologies, I overlooked the fact that I had a really long question. How may I be able to enable line breaks in question?

Comment: You would have to remove the <nobr> tag that holds the question (<nobr> prevents line breaks). My guess it can be done with a little javascript :)